# LVM + LUKS partition - Is this architecture dependent or independent?

Tags: lvm, 64bit, luks, 32bit

I've been recently dealing with an LVM + LUKS partition trying to install a new linux (ubuntu in this case).

I tried a few different options to make it work, but the pc resisted, the only system I could make work was the 32bit version of ubuntu 12.04. 
After succeeding with this (discarding all the twists to make the encryption work) I thought give it another try with the 64bit version since the pc is a 64bit after all.
But at this time I didn't re-set up the LVM nor re-partitioned it at all.

Right now, and just out of curiosity I would like to know, how architecture-dependant or not may an LVM partition be?

I mean, was I wrong by assumming I didn't need to repartition/reformat it before installing a 64bit system?

Thanks for any information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LVM/LUKS should not be architecture-dependant whatsoever, same goes for most filesystems. So a multiboot scenario where you have both 32bit and 64bit Linux installed and they share the same VG or access each others partitions, should be entirely possible.

You'll find the most dependencies in terms of software versions. For example recently a bug in the gcrypt/Whirlpool implementation was discovered, and the fix for that rendered LUKS containers using that algorithm unmountable. But it's not a default choice so the risk to be affected by this is low.

https://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#8._Issues_with_Specific_Versions_of_cryptsetup